# a-frame: Unable to change camera position and rotation angle

Tags: aframe

I am using the a-frame components for a WebVR application. The camera has look-controls with a cursor to let the user pick an object. And when the event is fired I wish to change the camera position. This is what I have done. A camera is defined in the scene.

```
<a-entity id="cam" camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls>
      <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03" material="color: black; shader: flat">
      </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

I have a box with a listener as follows

```
<a-box box-listener color="tomato" position="1 0 3" depth="1" height="1" width="1"></a-box>
```

When the user moves the cursor to the box and holds for half a second, the event gets fired. The event script is as follows:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('box-listener', {
      init: function() {
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
          var cam = document.getElementById("cam");
          var campos = cam.getAttribute("position");
          campos.x = 1; // some random change.
          var camrot = cam.getAttribute("rotation");
          camrot.x = 0;
          camrot.y = 0;
          camrot.z = 0; // setting it back to looking straight ahead
          var look = cam.getAttribute("look-controls");
          look.enabled = false;
          cam.setAttribute('look-controls',look);
          cam.setAttribute("position", campos);
          cam.setAttribute("rotation", camrot);
          look.enabled = true;
          cam.setAttribute('look-controls',look);
        });
      }
    });
```

By putting logs I find that the values are getting updated in the camera element however nothing changes on the screen.

where am I going wrong? Does the camera element need to be refreshed?

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/3qhpdq6v/

Comment: :-) ... checked the jsfiddle. Wonder why its not working on my page? Except I am using network-aframe. Let me change that and check. Thanks

Comment: The difference I found you are using 0.6.1 and I was using 0.6.0. Changing it to 0.6.1 got it working. I changed the jsfiddle to 0.6.0 and it did not work. Many thanks